# Spring Integration JMS - Spring code does commit on RuntimeException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, azureservicebus, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-queues

I would like to ask experienced Spring Integration developers or even code authors regarding weird behavior Im experiencing with my code. The issue is that Spring Code executes COMMIT on my RuntimeException. So here is my setup:

1.
I have standard JMS inbound channel adapter configured using

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter />
```

2. I have transactionManager which implements the Best effort 1PC pattern - that one available in Spring, ChainedTransactionManager.
3. Im consuming messages in simple testing flow where the JMS inbound adapter only publishes to direct channel and via one transformer endpoint the converted message is published to another direct endpoint where the handler which is ServiceActivator intentionally throws my application exception which extends RuntimeException.

Now when I debug the whole flow and when Im stepping through the Spring internal code I always end in place where the configured transaction manager calls COMMIT and thus my ChainedTransactionManager executes COMMIT as well despite Im simulating error and thus clear rollback scenario. The breakpoint in the rollback method is not hit at all.

What can I have wrong?

Now I have gone through the code again and even the Spring code sets the status to RollbackOnly and executes some exception handlers but at the end it still goes on successfully and ultimately it calls the commit line as shown on the screenshot and chainedTransactionManager instructs its local TMs to commit as well.

Im hoping there is some detail/mistake Im not able to spot :) Thanks!

Screenshot from class .m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jms\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-jms-5.2.3.RELEASE-sources.jar!\org\springframework\jms\listener\AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java

[image]

Comment: It looks like I dont understand the TM logic. Even the commit method takes the status as arg. and can do rollback. I thought these methods are exclusive - commit does commit, rollback does rollback. However when looking at TRACE logs I still dont know why it is mentioning nested transactions and resuming some suspended one. In my setup I should have single transaction started on JMS receive operation.

Comment: Sounds like would be better to share with us your configuration. Not clear why would one need a `ChainedTransactionManager` if only a JMS is involved...

Comment: Oh, I thought I have included the info, sorry  - it is implementation of message driven update in database. So two resources JMS and JDBC.

Comment: Anyway it looks like it is working fine, I was just confused that the rollback method is not called directly but instead commit is called with TransactionStatus set to Rollback. I think that opening 2 transactions - first for JMS resource and then for JDBC resource automatically means nested transactions, where JDBC is the inner one. Is that correct? If so, then all should be ok.

Comment: Yes. That's correct: we have a fake top-level chain transaction and those JMS & JDBC are nested to it.